# Trigger/Propagate Hover in Flash Actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, hover, actionscript-2, mouseover

I have multiple flash layers. The top layer `clickTag` is for catching the banner ad click and navigation to its landingpage.

However, when the user hovers the clickTag layer, I would also like to show the hover effect on a button in the `Button` layer below. But since the top layer is covering the whole space (width 100% x 100% height) of the banner, the hover effect of the button in the layer below never gets triggered.

How can I trigger/propagate the hover effect of the top layer to the button in a layer below?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this drawing api from  [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000381.html)

```
function drawRoundedRectangle(mc:MovieClip,rectWidth:Number, rectHeight:Number, cornerRadius:Number, fillColor:Number, fillAlpha:Number, lineThickness:Number, lineColor:Number, lineAlpha:Number) {
  with (mc) {
    beginFill(fillColor, fillAlpha);
    lineStyle(lineThickness, lineColor, lineAlpha);
    moveTo(cornerRadius, 0);
    lineTo(rectWidth - cornerRadius, 0);
    curveTo(rectWidth, 0, rectWidth, cornerRadius);
    lineTo(rectWidth, cornerRadius);
    lineTo(rectWidth, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
    curveTo(rectWidth, rectHeight, rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight);
    lineTo(rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight);
    lineTo(cornerRadius, rectHeight);
    curveTo(0, rectHeight, 0, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
    lineTo(0, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
    lineTo(0, cornerRadius);
    curveTo(0, 0, cornerRadius, 0);
    lineTo(cornerRadius, 0);
    endFill();
  }
}
```

This is for learning proposes strictly!!!

```
this.createEmptyMovieClip("th",100);
drawRoundedRectangle(th,100,50,5,0x00f999,100,1,0x000000,100);

th.onRollOver = function() {
decrement(th);
}

th.onRollOut = function() {
increment(th);
}  

function decrement(mc){
mc.onEnterFrame= function(){(th._alpha > 50)?th._alpha -= 9:delete this.onEnterFrame;}
}

function increment(mc){
mc.onEnterFrame= function(){(th._alpha < 100)?th._alpha += 5:delete this.onEnterFrame;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Soo many solutions, as create your costume button, listen for mouse placement in stage, and invoke button animation, wen mouse hovered specific region.

As if u are using button from Flash Componets menu, and you do not want to redraw that buttons style into your custom movie clip, here is one approach:

clickTag is applied to transparent movieClip right? Toogle into it to deepest possible level and just delete that region of bitmap, you want the button to be "seen" through, thus button actions will be seen now, through a hole in clickTag movieClip. // science

Comment: Thank you for your insight. However, I still want to have the clickTag action on the whole area. So, in the case of cutting out the button area, I would need to copy the clicktag action to the button as well, right?

Comment: Allright, i actually thought about that. A am pedantic my self.

How about listener for mouse placement, thus when she is hovered button, Button hover animation invoked, by function. I bet you could do that on custom made button. But if you muse Component button.. deep search needed..  [link](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/scripts/flash/components/)

Comment: nothing but [20 pence](http://docs.brajeshwar.com/as2/Button.html) on Button class methods. `btt.tabEnabled = true;
btt.tabIndex = 1;
btt.useHandCursor = true;
btt.onDragOver = true;`

Comment: Thank you. Since I'm a total beginner for Flash/ActionScript I use a standard Button. If you know how to (programatically) invoke the hover on a standard Button, please do write the ActionScript code - if possible. Thank you very much

Comment: Best would be for you to create a movie clip with three keyframes, holding button image of hovered and pressed and default button images. Then just goToAndStop(2); [HERE IS CODE](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?333832-AS2-rollovers) _samsung-rollover_ stands for instance name.

Comment: Yes, but there is issue, since animation(between button-state keyframes) made in GUI is invoked, it needs to finish the playback. I could make you drawing api for button made in code, thus animations made is more responsive, if do like, for example an increment of alpha while hovering button, and decrement on mouse out - even if button not fully incremented it's property, it would stop and decrement from that place as we rollOut of it.